# MOSFET (N) On resistance much higher than datasheet under load

Tags: mosfet, switches

This is my first post on this forum and I am hoping to be much more involved in this forum. I am currently designing  circuit that needs to switch a load of 200 mA by controlling its GND via a MOSFET (N). I chose a MOSFET with very low \$ R_{ds} \$ (On) of 25 mΩ ([DMG6968U](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds31738.pdf)) but when the load switches on the ON resitance goes up to 12 Ω causing  a large voltage drop. I am really confused. anyone know why is this happening.

Edit: I am simply tying the gate to +5v or GND to do the switching
Added the schematic.

[image]

Comment: What Vgs voltage are you using to turn the MOSFET on? Draw us a circuit if you doing anything 'unusual' to drive the MOSFET's gate.

Comment: Also, 12mOhm is *less* than 25mOhm - I assume that's a typo ... ?

Comment: RdsON also increases as the FET heats up...

Comment: Sorry a typo= at Id=200mA the RDS is 12Ohm I am simply tying the Gate to +5 or 0 to switch

Comment: Link to the thing's datasheet in your question.

Comment: the Rdson should not be anywhere near that high as the max Rdson is 25mOhm at 4.5Vgs and Id of 6.5A.  Either you have a bad part or there is something else going on, a schematic would be helpful.

Comment: Where did you buy it?

Comment: Dollars:donuts it's going to be source follower. But, you know, still no schematic.

Comment: @Asmyldof - well the OP writes "by controlling its GND via a MOSFET", which implies open-drain low-side switch ... but a schematic wouldn't leave us guessing.

Comment: @brhans  I added the schematic.Sorry I am new to this forum

Comment: I bough the part from Farnell

Comment: Why do you say that you have a resistance of 12 Ohm? How did you find that? What is the volage at the drain of the MOSFET?

Comment: Your numbers don't make sense. Even if the MOSFET were a dead short, 5V across 50ohms only gets you 100mA, not 200mA. How are you determining that the MOSFET's Rds(on) is 12ohms?

Comment: @brhans this is an example schematic I tried with various resistors. In this case it is 87mA and the drop is around 400mV 
(across drain and source) which means roughly 4.5 ohm Ids and also I measure the Rds under load (multi meter and ) it was around 3.8Ohm

Comment: @JaredGood Teh schematic example is now added

Comment: I predict this question is going to attract some vote-to-close-as-unclear pretty quickly unless you settle on one set of numbers and give a schematic which matches. There's also a schematic drawing tool built right into the question editor which produces much nicer to read drawings.

Comment: You can't measure resistance on a live circuit only voltage/current. You can calculate resistance knowing both. Your mulitimeter assumes the test current it supplies is the only current going into the DUT, which isn't true for a live circuit.

Comment: Are you sure you have connected the transistor correctly? That means the drain on top and the source to the ground? Please provide a proper schematic. Also, don't measure resistance under load; the measurement is not reliable.

Comment: Thank you all. I solved the problem. the problem was a resistance caused by cheap contacts to the PCB that holds the MOSFET they were adding about 4-5 Ohms to the circuit (Cheap breadboard) Thank you all for your responses. I changed the board and now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you all. I solved the problem. the problem was a resistance caused by cheap contacts to the PCB that holds the MOSFET they were adding about 4-5 Ohms to the circuit (Cheap breadboard) Thank you all for your responses. I changed the board and now it works perfectly.

Comment: In my case, cheap 'dupont' wires, 0.5 ohm each :)